# Camel content based router XPath empty soap returned

Tags: soap, cxf, apache-camel

I'm trying to retrieve a SOAP message from a CXF endpoint and then send that to a content based router which routes to a directory as an XML file.

This is the route in my camel-context:

```
<route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:reportIncident?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <xpath>/*/*/*[local-name()='inputReportIncident']/*[local-name()='familyName']='Holt'</xpath>
            <to uri="file:target/messages/contentbasedrouting/a?fileName=a.xml"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <to uri="file:target/messages/contentbasedrouting/otherwise?fileName=otherwise.xml"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice> 
</route>
```

The content based router works fine, but it sends a blank XML file to the directory and my SOAP message is gone.

If I pick up the SOAP message from a directory instead of a CXF endpoint it works fine. If I did:

```
<from uri="file:target/messages/incoming"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<from uri="cxf:bean:reportIncident?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I figured out why. Stream types can only be read once. In order to be able to work with message content multiple times, the stream needs to be cached. To do so add streamCache="true" to <route>. See http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its due streaming. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html